# HTML Mustache notation showing nothing in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, json

I am working on displaying an unordered list that I am adding to the scope with a JSON endpoint. I am receiving the dictionary from the endpoint correctly, but when I used mustache notation I'm getting blank list items.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="AppointmentTrackerApp">
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="../static/js/ng-controller.js"></script>
<script src="js/ng-controller.js"></script>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>HomePage</title>
</head>
<body ng-controller="ng-controller">
<div>
    <br>
        <button ng-click="showme=true" ng-hide="showme">New</button>
    <div ng-show="showme">
        <input type="button" ng-click="addAppointment()" value="Add"/><button ng-click="showme=false" ng-show="showme">Cancel</button>
        </br></br>
            Date: <input type="text" ng-model="newAppointment.appDate"></br>
            Time: <input type="text" ng-model="newAppointment.appTime"></br>
            Description: <input type="text" ng-model="newAppointment.description">
    </div>
</div>

</br></br>
<input type="text" name="searchText"><input type="button" ng-click="getAppointments()" value="Search"/>
</br></br>
<ul>
<li ng-repeat="appointment in appointments"></li>
    {{appointment.appDate}} {{appointment.appTime}} {{appointment.description}}
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the JSON dictionary I'm receiving:

```
[
{
id: 4,
appDate: "1",
appTime: "2",
description: "3"
},
{
id: 5,
appDate: "2",
appTime: "3",
description: "4"
},
{
id: 6,
appDate: "3",
appTime: "4",
description: "5"
},
{
id: 7,
appDate: "4",
appTime: "5",
description: "6"
}
]
```

and here is the result I see:
[image: screen clipping]

Comment: You'll need to tell us what your app/controller looks like.

Comment: Additionally, your mustache code is outside of your <li> tags.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan, do you need the RESTController or the JSController?

Comment: I don't need anything :). Your question could benefit from having the code for "ng-controller" (the controller, not the built-in directive; might want to change the name of that, BTW) in the question. However, if Ryan and Sanket are correct, and you just misplaced the code, I'd just delete the question.

Comment: @RyanGibbs Thanks that solved it for me, someone answered it as well with a response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to reference `appointment` outside of the `ng-repeat` directive. This should fix it -

```
<li ng-repeat="appointment in appointments">
    {{appointment.appDate}} {{appointment.appTime}} {{appointment.description}}
</li>
```

Having a proper indentation would be helpful to fix problems like these. Please make sure to use consistent indentation in your templates

Comment: Thanks, it always turns out to be the little things.